iOS app shown in Firebase `Release Monitoring` but not in `Analytics Dashboard`
About six months ago, I upgraded the Firebase version used in the iOS app I'm working on from 10.3.0 to 10.21.0 and created a new app release.  Since that app release, I am no longer able to view information for each new iOS release in the Firebase console "Analytics Dashboard".  Although, all my latest iOS app releases show up as expected in the Firebase console "Release Monitoring".
I did another iOS app release recently, where I upgrade Firebase to 10.28.1 and also redownloaded the GoogleService-Info.plist.  But I'm still having the same issue.  Was there a change to Firebase-Analytics API that I missed?  Or some other setting that need be enabled?

I have the exact same problem. My most recent release updated Firebase to 10.29.0. It can no longer be seen in Analytics Dashboard, but does show in the new Release Monitoring experience. I'm wondering if somehow the "sessions capable" SDKs don't report to Analytics Dashboard? https://firebase.google.com/docs/release/release-monitoring?hl=en&authuser=0#which-builds-can-be-viewed
